# Design patterns for implementing optionally supported features

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

Here's the original problem. There are two classes: Protocol and, say, ProtocolUser (which actully uses the Protocol class instance). Now, I need to support multiple protocols, whose feature sets only partly intersect, doing similar but not equal things. I grouped the features into several interfaces. That is:

```
interface IA {}
interface IB {}
interface IC {}

interface IP {};
class P_AB : IP, IA, IB {}
class P_AC : IP, IA, IC {}
class P_BC : IP, IB,IC {}

class P_User
{
    IP m_p;

    ??? // needs to use m_p via IA, IB or IC, depending on which are supported
}
```

And the most vexed part: the protocols are to be switched on-the-fly. Methods of `P_User` will have to choose which interfaces to operate on, depending on which will be supported by the call time.

The initial plan was to rely on `is` & `as` operators. But it does look suspiciously cumbersome. The only alternative I see is to invent some kind of "CanDoThis / CanDoThat" infrastructure, but that doesn't differ much from a plain `is`.

Are there any helpful patterns I'm unaware of?

Comment: "it does look suspiciously cumbersome" In what way?

Comment: @pdr the 'if else if' train strongly reminds me of the switch-by-type situation, where polymorphism can often fit better. But I don't clearly see it here, either...

Comment: I see why it appears that way, but it's not. As opposed to "if this condition, use this type, else if this condition, use another type, etc" this is "if the current protocol supports X, use it; if it supports Y, use it; if it supports Z, use it." The alternative is to have no-op methods in each protocol class and call them all, which is pretty hard to follow at scale. "Can" methods, as you point out, are no different from is and as.

Comment: @pdr Yeah, that's exactly why I decided to try anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have really two options here:

- factoring - isolate interfaces of each object and use soft casting (as operator) to determine extended capabilities of the class
- optional feature pattern - implement all methods available on all classes in one base class and throw `NotSupportedException` when the given function is not supported.

Both of those have their pros and cons: 
Factoring:

- pro: responsibilities/capabilities of your code are well separated
- con: the code becomes more complex, and functionality hard to discover

Optional features pattern:

- pro: Functionality is easier to discover using tools like Intellisense
- con: The base class is bloated with unnecessary functions that might throw

Since you've said that your interfaces should intersect only a little I would go with the factoring approach, it is more suited for such cases. A more realistic example would be needed to give you more detailed answer.

Edit: If some of the interface combinations are expected to be used more than other you might consider combining them in another interface:

```
public interface IAB : IA, IB
```

This would of course result in interface explosion if you did it for every possible combination, so use this sparingly only in cases where it really makes sense. It's always easier to add a new interface than to remove one.

Answer (score 4):

[Dependency Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) should be best fit in your case.

The interfaces should not be defined based on supported capabilities, but on what `P_User` is expecting from the protocol. Each protocol can then implemented what `P_User` needs based on it's capabilities.

Comment: I think that using the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern would help the OP achieve this.

Comment: I think the point here is that P_User doesn't EXPECT anything of m_p, but if things are provided then it uses them. I don't see how DIP solves that problem.

Comment: Yes, @pdr is right, that's the case. I've considered strategies as well, but the protocol classes often have internal state, and it doesn't play well with a strategy set. It can be done, but unlikely to be simpler...

Comment: @vines How internal state doesn't play well with strategy?

Comment: @Euphoric Virtually any of the strategies would have to be able to switch the state and other parallel strategies in a batch. I hardly see how to do it without weaving too many interdependencies or noticeable marshalling complication. (Also, a set of strategies doesn't just look as a right abstraction for a single protocol, but that's debatable.)

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is a variation of an Abstract Factory. Something like this:

```
public class ProtocolFactory
{
    public IP _protocol;

    public ProtocolFactory(IP protocol)
    {
         _protocol = protocol;
    }

    public IA GetAService()
    {
         return _protocol as IA ?? new NoOpProtocol();
    }

    public IB GetBService()
    {
         return _protocol as IB ?? new NoOpProtocol();
    }

    // etc
}

public class NoOpProtocol : IA, IB, IC
{
     // Implement all interfaces as no-ops
}
```

So now your calling code is

```
var factory = new ProtocolFactory(m_p);
factory.GetAService().DoStuff();
factory.GetBService().DoMore();
// etc
```

This seems less cumbersome, keeps the soft-casting functionality in one place, but still allows you extensibility, with as many protocols as you like, each implementing as few or as many interfaces as you like.

Comment: This is an interesting sort of "reverse" visitor pattern. There is an explicit type check, but it is hidden inside of the factory, and the use of the null object means that no one is the wiser.

Comment: Yes, interesting solution. Unfortunately, the actual method usage logic differs so much that it just won't fit into a no-op scheme... Otherwise I'd considered doing it :)